# "Converting" in jQuery an audio player with multiple tracks

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have a tracklist and I'd like to serve a preview of 3 songs with just a play and pause button.

Here's the messy snippet I have right now in JS:

```
var playing = false;
playpause01.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (!playing) {
        document.getElementById('player01').play();
        this.src = 'files/img/pause.png';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('player01').pause();
        this.src = 'files/img/play.png';
    }
    playing = !playing;
});
playpause04.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (!playing) {
        document.getElementById('player04').play();
        this.src = 'files/img/pause.png';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('player04').pause();
        this.src = 'files/img/play.png';
    }
    playing = !playing;
});
playpause13.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (!playing) {
        document.getElementById('player13').play();
        this.src = 'files/img/pause.png';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('player13').pause();
        this.src = 'files/img/play.png';
    }
    playing = !playing;
});
```

And for each track I have in HTML:

```
<audio id="player01" src="files/blabla.ogg"></audio>
        <img style="position:absolute;left:-80px" id="playpause01" src="files/img/play.png" />
```

Now, this snippet has 2 issues:
1) I need to separetely target 3 different elements (for each song I want to preview)
2) If I play a new song while playing one the 2 songs overlap.

I think rewriting the snippet in jQuery would be much easier. How could I solve the 2 issues?

Here's the JsFiddle to start from:
http://jsfiddle.net/multiformeingegno/jdk0b5L4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a common listener like this:

```
$('ol').on('click', 'li img', playAudio);
var currentlyPlaying;
function playAudio(e){
    var audElement = $(e.target).siblings('audio')[0];
    window.aa = audElement;
    if(audElement && audElement.paused){
        if(currentlyPlaying)
            currentlyPlaying.pause();            
        currentlyPlaying = audElement;
        addListeners(currentlyPlaying);
        currentlyPlaying.play();            
    }else if(audElement){
        audElement.pause();
    }
}

function addListeners(aud){
    aud.removeEventListener('ended', onPause);  // remove done to remove previous listener
    aud.removeEventListener('pause', onPause);
    aud.removeEventListener('playing', onPlay);
    aud.addEventListener('ended', onPause);
    aud.addEventListener('pause', onPause);
    aud.addEventListener('playing', onPlay);
}

function onPlay(e){
    $(e.target).siblings('img')[0].src = 'http://luca-longobardi.com/files/img/pause.png';
}
function onPause(e){
    e.target.currentTime = 0;   // reset to beginning
    $(e.target).siblings('img')[0].src = 'http://luca-longobardi.com/files/img/play.png';
}
```

#### [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt5vzubv/1/)

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno, one track fades and other starts?

Comment: Yes, when I click the play button if a track is already playing it fades and the other starts

Comment: ya, that's gonna be tricky, you might need to use `web-audio`, here is an example of [cross-fade](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/#toc-xfade)